# How to compare two ParametriPlots for different problems?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, equation-solving, image-processing

I have solved the following problem for these two situations and created their plots.  Now I want to contrast the same axis system in the two plots. I used `Show[{q1, curve},{t,0,200}]` but it did not work and it is normal because I have used the `` Clear["Global`*"] ``. How do I have to act in this case?

```
Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 0.9;
\[Beta] = 0.2;
\[Gamma] = 1.2;
f[x_, y_, z_] := z + (y - \[Alpha])*x
g[x_, y_, z_] := 1 - \[Beta]*y - x^2
p[x_, y_, z_] := -x - \[Gamma]*z
Q[a_, b_, c_, h_, N_] := (u[0] = a; v[0] = b; w[0] = c;
   Do[{u[n + 1] = 
      u[n] + h*
        f[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]], 
     v[n + 1] = 
      v[n] + h*
        g[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]], 
     w[n + 1] = 
      w[n] + h*
        p[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]]}, {n, 0, N}]);
Q[1, 3, 2, 0.1, 1000]
Table[u[n], {n, 0, 1000, 50}]
X = Interpolation[Table[{n, u[n]}, {n, 0, 1000}]]

Y = Interpolation[Table[{n, v[n]}, {n, 0, 1000}]]

Z = Interpolation[Table[{n, w[n]}, {n, 0, 1000}]]

ParametricPlot3D[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}]

q1 = Plot[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, 1000}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

```
Clear["Global`*"];
\[Alpha] = 0.9;
\[Beta] = 0.2;
\[Gamma] = 1.2;
f[x_, y_, z_] := z + (y - \[Alpha])*x
g[x_, y_, z_] := 1 - \[Beta]*y - x^2
p[x_, y_, z_] := -x - \[Gamma]*z
Q[a_, b_, c_, h_, N_] := (u[0] = a; v[0] = b; w[0] = c;
   Do[{u[n + 1] = 
      u[n] + h*
        f[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]], 
     v[n + 1] = 
      v[n] + h*
        g[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]], 
     w[n + 1] = 
      w[n] + h*
        p[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]], 
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]]}, {n, 0, N}]);

Q[1.001, 3.001, 2.001, 0.1, 1000]
Table[u[n], {n, 0, 1000, 50}]
X = Interpolation[Table[{n, u[n]}, {n, 0, 1000}]]
Y = Interpolation[Table[{n, v[n]}, {n, 0, 1000}]]
Z = Interpolation[Table[{n, w[n]}, {n, 0, 1000}]]
ParametricPlot3D[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, 200}]
curve=Plot[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, 200}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

Comment: Learn about [modularity and scoping constructs](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ModularityAndTheNamingOfThings.html) in Mathematica, and don't use ``Clear["Global`*"]`` when it is not needed.

Comment: Thanks. I have never faced something like this before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
α = 0.9;
β = 0.2;
γ = 1.2;
f[x_, y_, z_] := z + (y - α)*x
g[x_, y_, z_] := 1 - β*y - x^2
p[x_, y_, z_] := -x - γ*z

Q[a_, b_, c_, h_, NN_] := (
   u[0] = a; v[0] = b; w[0] = c;
   Do[{u[n + 1] =
      u[n] + h*f[u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]],
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]],
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]],
     v[n + 1] = v[n] + h*g[
         u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]],
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]],
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]],
     w[n + 1] = w[n] + h*p[
         u[n] + h/2*f[u[n], v[n], w[n]],
         v[n] + h/2*g[u[n], v[n], w[n]],
         w[n] + h/2*p[u[n], v[n], w[n]]]},
    {n, 0, NN}]);

params = {
   {1, 3, 2, 0.1, 1000},
   {1.001, 3.001, 2.001, 0.1, 1000}};
```

Plotting,

```
Manipulate[Module[{a, b, c, h, NN},
  {a, b, c, h, NN} = params[[p]];
  Q[a, b, c, h, NN];
  X = Interpolation[Table[{n, u[n]}, {n, 0, NN}]];
  Y = Interpolation[Table[{n, v[n]}, {n, 0, NN}]];
  Z = Interpolation[Table[{n, w[n]}, {n, 0, NN}]];
  Column[If[rev, Reverse, Identity]@{
     Legended[
      ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate@{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]},
       {t, int[[1]], int[[2]]},
       PlotRange -> {{-2.25, 3}, {-1.6, 3.25}, {-1.25, 2}},
       PlotPoints -> 150, MaxRecursion -> 5,
       AxesLabel -> (Style[#, 14] & /@ {"X", "Y", "Z"}),
       ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z, t},
         ColorData["Rainbow"][t/1000]],
       ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
       ImageSize -> Medium],
      BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {0, 1000}},
       LegendLabel -> t]],
     Plot[{X[t], Y[t], Z[t]}, {t, 0, 1000},
      PlotLegends -> "Expressions",
      Frame -> True, ImageSize -> Medium]}]],
 {{p, 1, "parameters"}, Thread[Range[Length@params] ->
    (StringForm[
        "a=``,\[ThinSpace]b=``,\[ThinSpace]c=``,\[ThinSpace]h=``,\
\[ThinSpace]NN=``",
        Sequence @@ #] & /@ params)]},
 Row[{Control[{{int, {0, 1000}, "t interval"}, 0, 1000, 25,
     ControlType -> IntervalSlider,
     Method -> "Push", MinIntervalSize -> 25,
     Appearance -> "Labeled"}],
   Control[{{rev, False, "Reverse"}, {True, False}}]}],
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 TrackedSymbols :> {p, int, rev}]
```

[image]